# Why are Firefox fonts so tiny on KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, fonts, kde

I use Firefox 10 on Ubuntu 12.04, in KDE.

In for instance Chrome and Konqueror, the fonts look alright, but in Firefox the fonts are tiny, almost too hard to read.

Comment: Did you accidentally change the page zoom? Try `View > Zoom > Reset` or `Ctrl`+`0`.

Comment: No, good tip though, didn't know about Ctrl + 0! @iglvzx

Comment: Go to `chrome://browser/content/preferences/fonts.xul` ... What do you see there? The font size should be `16` for proportional and `12` or `13` for monospace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common cases for the fonts appearing too small in Firefox.

### Case 1:

You may have accidentally changed the page zoom. Set the page zoom back to `100%` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or using the GUI: `View > Zoom > Reset`.

**Note:** There is a related preference in `about:config` for remembering page specific zoom levels. If you do not care for this feature, or frequently change the zoom level by accident, you can set the following to **false**:

```
browser.zoom.siteSpecific
```

Now when you go back to a page, the zoom level will be reset to `100%`.

### Case 2:

Your Firefox profile's font settings may have been altered. Go to:

```
chrome://browser/content/preferences/fonts.xul
```

The font size should be `16` for **Proportional** and `12` or `13` for **Monospace**.

**Note:** These settings can also be reached under:

```
Preferences/Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced
```

Answer (score 0):

firefox (72) can't find "chrome://browser/content/preferences/fonts.xul"...
Preferences/Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced is meant for web pages, not for tab or bookmark fonts...